# print the given string via the selected printer in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, printing

initially I will give what are the printers connected to my laptop to the user.

then user will have to choose the printer name and some string.

my task is to print the given string via the selected printer.

`
@GetMapping("/printPreview")
public String printpage(@RequestBody PrinterOutput printerOutput) throws Exception {
String input = printerOutput.getContent(); // Replace with your desired input

```
    // Print the input string
    try {
        // Create a printer job
        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

        // Get the default printer
        PrintService defaultPrintService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();

        // Set the default printer for the job
        job.setPrintService(defaultPrintService);

        // Set a printable object
        job.setPrintable(new Printable() {
            @Override
            public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {
                if (pageIndex > 0)
                {
                    return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
                }

                // Get the graphics context
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphics;

                // Set the font and position for printing
                g2d.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12));
                g2d.translate(pageFormat.getImageableX(), pageFormat.getImageableY());

                // Print the input string
                g2d.drawString(input, 5, 12);

                return PAGE_EXISTS;
            }
        });

        job.setCopies(1);
        // Send the job to the printer
        job.print();
        System.out.println("printing");
    } catch (PrinterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "Sucess";
}
```

the above code is working find but it is printing only via default printer, i want it to be via the selected printer.

```
 @GetMapping("/print")
    public String printDemo(@RequestBody PrinterOutput printerOutput) throws Exception {
        String input = printerOutput.getContent(); // Replace with your desired input
        String printerName = printerOutput.getPrinterName();
        // Print the input string
        try {
            // Get the print service for the specified printer name
            PrintService printService = findPrintService(printerName);

            if (printService == null) {
                return "Printer not found: " + printerName;
            }

            // Create a printer job
            PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

            // Set the print service for the job
            job.setPrintService(printService);

            // Set a printable object
            job.setPrintable(new Printable() {
                @Override
                public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {
                    if (pageIndex > 0) {
                        return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
                    }

                    // Get the graphics context
                    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphics;

                    // Set the font and position for printing
                    g2d.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12));
                    g2d.translate(pageFormat.getImageableX(), pageFormat.getImageableY());

                    // Print the input string
                    g2d.drawString(input, 5, 12);

                    return PAGE_EXISTS;
                }
            });

            job.setCopies(1);
            // Send the job to the printer
            job.print();
            System.out.println("Printing to: " + printerName);
        } catch (PrinterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Failed to print: " + e.getMessage();
        }

        return "Success";
    }

    private PrintService findPrintService(String printerName) {
        PrintService[] printServices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);

        for (PrintService printService : printServices) {
            if (printService.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(printerName)) {
                return printService;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

this is what i have tried but not working as expected.